# Python 2.7 Get return value from function without running what is in the function again?

Tags: python, function, return

I am trying to get the return value of a function.. but I do not want the function to run again. It's speech recognition, and so, every time it runs again it tries to see what the user said. I just need the variable saved. I am avoiding using global variables.

```
def voiceRecognition(self):
    <A bunch of voice recognition stuff here>
    return whatUserSaid
```

The code where I call it:

```
 SPEECH.voiceRecognition()
```

The reason for SPEECH and self is b/c it is part of a class and I am calling it in a different Python file. Right now it is working... I just need to only return the variable whatUserSaid, not have the function re-run through what it did to get the value. How do I do this?

Comment: So, where is your code?

Comment: need to show some code - you know that when you call a function you can assign it to a variable - if you want to avoid globals, then you will need to think about classes.

Comment: we need to see the code when you call that function !

Comment: Sorry I just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your given code, it looks like you've built this into a class so I'm going to make some assumptions on that.

```
class VoiceRecognizer(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.last_phrase = None

    def voiceRecognition(self):
        # your code here
        self.last_phrase = whatUserSaid
        return whatUserSaid
```

This should let you do things like:

```
v = VoiceRecognizer()
v.voiceRecognition()
v.last_phrase # is the last return of voiceRecognition
```

But I'm not really sure WHY you want to do this. Can't you just save it to a variable?

```
last_phrase = v.voiceRecognition() # like this?
```

Comment: That worked... thank you. I couldn't just do that, because the module I'm using is absolute garbage. I actually had to edit it a bit to even make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a class instance and memoize the value.

```
class VoiceRecognizer():

     def __init__(self):
         self._parsed = {}

     def recognize(self, speech):
         key = function_to_turn_speech_into_unique_string(speech)
         if key not in self._parsed:
             self._parsed[key] = recognize_function(speech)
         return self._parsed[key]

 recognizer = VoiceRecognizer()
 recognizer.recognize(speechA)  # will compute
 recognizer.recognize(speechA)  # will use cache
 recognizer.recognize(speechB)  # will compute if speechA == speechB
```

Comment: the first time you put something new into the `recognize` method you'll fail on recursion too deep

Comment: Took me a minute to realize what you were talking about -- we're both wrong.  The code would error, but with `NameError: global name 'recognize' is not defined`.  I intended to call the existing `recognize` -- not `self.recognize` -- so I renamed it `recognize_function`.